# Problems when updating MySQL 5.0 to 5.5

Tags: mysql

I have a db hosted at Godaddy.
I've made a backup of my MySQL 5.0 database.
I deleted the db.
I've made a new db which uses MySQL 5.5
with the same password as used before.

Now I can't connect, and am getting this error message:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Godaddy's database details menu the hostname is incorrect.** I had to get into phpmyadmin and copy the IP address shown there. Using that when connecting via PHP makes everything okay.